# Which version of geomesa-accumulo to install on Spark 3.3.0

Tags: geomesa

I need to install geomesa-accumulo on Spark 3.3.0 using a Docker container. In particular, I'm using the jupyter/pyspark-notebook image and I have tried to install geomesa-accumulo_2.11-2.0.0, but there seems to be an incompatibility problem. I think I should use another version of geoserver-accumulo, but I can't find references to figure out which version to install.

From this code snippet, I get the following error.

```
val dataStoreParams = Map( 
    "geotools" -> "true", 
    "dbtype" -> "postgis",
    "host" -> "backend-postgres", 
    "user" -> "postgres", 
    "passwd" -> "mypassword", 
    "port" -> "5432", 
    "database" -> "dev")

val dataStore = DataStoreFinder.getDataStore(dataStoreParams);
```

warning: one deprecation (since 2.12.0); for details, enable `:setting -deprecation' or` :replay -deprecation'
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.geotools.data.DataStoreFactorySpi is not an ImageIO SPI class
at java.desktop/javax.imageio.spi.ServiceRegistry.checkClassAllowed(ServiceRegistry.java:716)
at java.desktop/javax.imageio.spi.ServiceRegistry.(ServiceRegistry.java:117)
at org.geotools.factory.FactoryRegistry.(FactoryRegistry.java:155)
at org.geotools.factory.FactoryCreator.(FactoryCreator.java:91)
at org.geotools.data.DataStoreFinder.getServiceRegistry(DataStoreFinder.java:128)
at org.geotools.data.DataStoreFinder.getAvailableDataStores(DataStoreFinder.java:115)
at org.geotools.data.DataStoreFinder.getDataStore(DataStoreFinder.java:87)
... 42 elided

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following maven dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.locationtech.geomesa</groupId>
    <artifactId>geomesa-accumulo-spark_2.11</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.0</version>
</dependency>
```

**References:**

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.locationtech.geomesa/geomesa-accumulo-spark_2.11

Answer (score 0):

There are instructions for installing into Jupyter Notebook in the GeoMesa [documentation](https://www.geomesa.org/documentation/stable/user/spark/jupyter.html), including the jars to use. Please note that at the time of this post, the latest version of GeoMesa is 3.4.1, and it officially supports up to [Spark 3.1](https://www.geomesa.org/documentation/stable/user/spark/index.html), so you may hit incompatibilities.

When you install, make sure that you use the appropriate Scala version for your version of Spark - Spark 3.3.0 by default uses Scala 2.12, so you would need to use GeoMesa artifacts ending with `_2.12`.